# Looking for a free software that deals with spam issues?

Tags: open-source, email, spam

I'm looking for software that can prevent our junk email we get like 100's daily. We have MSN| Outlook, Office, Skype, Bing outlook.com email account and want to know if there is a better way to lessen spam or junkie email we get ?

Do you have some suggest that we can take look at it ?

Comment: spamassassin, rspamd, etc.

Comment: @sebix - Do you mean the word you spell are the name of the software ?

Comment: Yes, these are spam detection programs